# How do I include and use Javascript files from the web into my Angular application?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

My Angular (5) application needs to rely on code in a .js file which is stored online. I can't download this file as its content frequently changes and I always want to use the latest version that is stored online.

When I include it in the index.html file by using the `<script>` elements, its functions aren't accessible from my components and I get some errors in the terminal.

I can't find documentation on this.

Comment: Do you get errors at *compile time*, or at *run time*? If it's compile errors (TSxxxx) then you probably just need to `declare` the global names you're referring to from that JS file. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide some code snippet